# virNetSocketReadWire:1801 : End of file while reading data: Input/output error

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm, libvirt

Every time I start/stop a KVM, the `libvirtd 3.0.0-4` throws the following error in syslog:

```
libvirtd[3145]: 2018-08-07 21:00:19.699+0000: 3145: \
    error : qemuMonitorIO:710 : internal error: \
    End of file from qemu m     onitor
virtlogd[2753]: 2018-08-07 21:00:19.901+0000: 2753: \
    error : virNetSocketReadWire:1801 : \
    End of file while reading data: Input/output error
```

Does anyone experience the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are missing the driver:

`yum -y install libvirt-daemon-driver-qemu && systemctl restart libvirtd`

Comment: No, I'm not, all drivers are installed.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have to remove nat related modules from /etc/modprobe.d/nf-blacklist.conf. Otherwise, those module won't be load and virsh network got stuck.

You can check if you have nat modules by lsmod | grep nat, good output:

```
lsmod | grep nat
nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4    16384  1 ipt_MASQUERADE
iptable_nat            16384  1
nf_nat_ipv4            16384  1 iptable_nat
nf_nat                 36864  2 nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4,nf_nat_ipv4
nf_conntrack          155648  6 xt_conntrack,nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4,nf_conntrack_ipv4,nf_nat,ipt_MASQUERADE,nf_nat_ipv4
ip_tables              28672  3 iptable_filter,iptable_nat,iptable_mangle
libcrc32c              16384  3 nf_conntrack,nf_nat,raid456
```